# Why are my elements changing position when I zoom?

Tags: css, position

I am working on this site. When I zoom in the browser (ctr +/-) the elements at the top change position (the menu, and featured slider). Is there a way to make them stay in the some position no matter what the zoom.

Here is a link to the site - http://www.independentlynew.com/dev/5church

[image: Here is a screenshot of the correct positioning]

[image: Here is a screenshot of the incorrect positioning after zooming]

Comment: What browser? In Firefox, zooming works beautifully. In IE9, the menu is ok, but the background is broken. In Chrome, the site doesn't work even without zooming.

Comment: This incorrect positioning is the default I am getting without zooming my browser (Chrome 20.0.1121.0 canary on mac) are you still playing about with the styles?

Comment: Images are no longer available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems like the main menu container is overflowing the logo container, causing it be pushed upwards. this is likely to be caused by those containers having an access margin or padding, fitting exactly into their wrapper, and the browser's rounding method used during the zoom.

try and remove the left padding from the `#menu` container:

```css
#menu {
    float: right;
    background: url(images/left-menu-bg.png) no-repeat top left;
    /* padding-left: 12px; */
    height: 48px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: that definitely helped. it messes up at less of the zoom levels, but still happens at a few of them. you can check the site, i updated the code per your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: if you find the answer useful, it is of courtesy to up-vote it.

Comment: i'm new to this forum. didn't know about the up voting, but it will not let me do it anyways, says I need more "reputation"

Comment: thanks anyway, and welcome aboard. feel free to look around, but be sure to visit the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) first. see you around!

Comment: Thanks. I removed some more padding from the #menu-right container. That helped a lot two. It seems like there is still one zoom level where the elements shift position, but one, so probally not a big deal. If you have any other suggestions let me know, if not thanks for other advice it is way better now.

Answer (score 0):

The browsers often have poor zooming algorithms that lead to rounding errors manifesting themselves when zoomed in or out.

I believe this is more of a user agent issue, as the iOS version of Safari has no issues performing zoom, while other browsers do.